# A question about the infinite neighborhoods of a limit point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> If $p$ is a limit point of a subset $E$ of a metric space $X,$ then for any $r > 0, \ N_r(p)$ contains infinitely many points of $E.$

Proof's given below with bits and pieces missing. I am having difficulty with $N_h(p) \cap Q =$ ____ Suppose it's $N_h(p) - \{p\}.$ Now we want $N_h(p) - \{p\} = \emptyset.$ But $N_h(p) - \{p\} \subset N_r(p) (?)$ and $N_r(p) \cap E$ has a finite number of elements of $E.$ So I am wondering how do we know (if we do) some of the elements of $E$ not in $N_h(p)$? If all this is incorrect what is $N_h(p) \cap Q?$ Thanks.

[image]

Comment: From which book did you take that from?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Real-Analysis-Lifesaver-Understand-Princeton-ebook/dp/B01IFYRIO8/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1502574593&sr=8-1&keywords=grinberg

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: The first 3 blanks are, in order, (1) finite (2) $\min D,$ (3) positive (4). The 2nd-last blank is $\{p\} and the last blank is "limit point".

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, thanks. So far $N_h(p) \cap Q$ remains super mysterious for some reason :) All we need to show is $N_h(p) \cap Q = \{\}.$

Comment: Any member of $N_h(p)$ is closer to $p$ than any member of $Q$  is, because $y'in Q\implies d(y,p)\geq \min D>h.$ For the proof it would suffice to let $h=\min D\}$.... BTW a more common notation for $N_r(p)$ is $B_d(p,r),$ and when only one metric $d$ is in play, $B(p,r)$ is common.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, thanks. How about the following: $0 < h < \min D \implies q_i \not \in N_h(p) \implies N_h(p) \cap Q = \emptyset?$

Comment: Yes. That's fine.///////////

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the proof is over complicated. You can give a constructive proof of the statement by constructing two sequences ($(r_i\ ;\ q_i\ i\geq 1)$ as follows. Starting with $r\mbox{ and } q_1\in (E\setminus\{p\})\cap N_r(p)$,  you suppose that $r_i,\ q_i$ are constructed up to $i=N$, the next step is then
$$
r_{N+1}=\frac{d(p,q_N)}{2}\ ;\ q_{N+1}\in (E\setminus\{p\})\cap N_1(p)
$$
it is not difficult to see that $d(p,q_i)$ is strictly decreasing and then all $\{q_i\}_{i\geq 1}$ are different.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative proof. The proof given in my OP occurs in a chapter that precedes the ones that introduce sequences.

Answer (score 0):

All that is needed is to show every open nhood of p is infinite
is merely that X is T1, ie all singletons are closed.

Assume p in open U.  There is some x1 in U different than p.
Since p in open U - {x1}, there is some x2 in U - {x1}. x2 is different than p and x1.
Continue with U - {x1,x2} etc. to produce an infinite sequence of distinct points in U.